# Removing elements in Python with ET

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

My code seems to be getting a value error and I am not sure why.

```
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

When I use a print statement I seem to find the log setting correctly because it prints the location and number I would expect to see.  I am just not sure why I can't remove it.

```
XML
...
<security>
    <rules>
        <entry name="blah">
            <log-setting> log-forwarding-main
```

And here is the two scipts I have tried

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('filelocation')
rules = tree.findall('.//security/rules/entry')

for rem_rule in rules:
    log = rem_rule.findall('log-setting')
    rem_rule.remove(log)
tree.write('newfilelocation')
```

And tried this per a different post

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('filelocation')
rules = tree.findall('.//security/rules/entry')

for rem_rule in rules[:]:
    for rem_rule in rules[:]:
        log = rem_rule.findall('log-setting')
        rem_rule.remove(log)
tree.write('newfilelocation')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation `xml.etree.ElementTree.Element` has a function `.remove(subelement)`. However, `.findall()` will return a list. Thus, replacing `rem_rule.remove(log)` with:

```
for element in log:
    rem_rule.remove(element)
```

solves the problem. Your complete snippet then looks like

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
rules = tree.findall('.//security/rules/entry')

for rem_rule in rules:
    log = rem_rule.findall('log-setting')
    for element in log:
        rem_rule.remove(element)
tree.write('newtest.xml')
```

Comment: This worked like a charm, thanks for helping a noob out.  Not really a coder at all but this just saved my a lot of time in my future tasks.